# windowOpened in java not working

Tags: java, windowlistener

Everytime I open my frame, windowOpened should print "opened" but it does not. All other abstract methods are working properly. I'm using Java 7. Any ideas for this behavior.

```
public class windowlistenerdemo extends Frame implements WindowListener 
{
    public windowlistenerdemo()
    {
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        this.addWindowListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("open");
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("closing");
        this.dispose();
     }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("closed");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        windowlistenerdemo ob = new windowlistenerdemo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   setVisible(true);
   this.addWindowListener(this);
```

You are setting the window to be visible before adding the `listener`. The `windowOpened` event has already fired. Try swapping these lines.